# How to display banner in list page?

Tags: image, product-list

I want to display dynamic banners in list page with respect to the categories. I tried creating a `static block` at admin panel and selecting it in `CMS Block` option in `Display Settings` tab of specific category. But No banner image is displayed at list page. Below is the code which I used in static block to display a banner there:

```
    <div id="banner1" class="slide"  style="display:block;">
 <a class="banner-home" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 981px; height: 342px;"  href=""> 
    <img  src="{{media url="wysiwyg/banner1.jpg"}}" alt=""> 
  </a>
</div>
```

Please correct me If am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have selected `Display Settings->Display Mode = Static block and products`

FYI: you can also assign image for each category then display corresponding image on category page.

Comment: Yea I did It  & Posted the same answer just now. Anyway thanks for your response I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a small mistake I did. When I selected `Static block and Product` option in `Display mode` the static block which I created and added for that category displayed.

I think this answer may help someone.